Configuration error when using remote server
I tried to connect to a remote server and configure the conda interpreter on pycharm2023 Professional. The connection worked but the following error occurred when configuring the server: "Java. Lang. An IllegalStateException: Expected the BEGIN OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path error", could you tell me how to solve? Thanks
it can be connected successfully if using virtualenv
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
